# What causes a high Scan Count in SQL Server IO Statistics?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I understand that these are table or index scans that are being performed.  I'm a little unclear on what would cause some tables to have a large scan count while others would have a small scan count.  In a query I am looking at right now i am getting a scan count of about 150,000 on two tables in my query, while the rest have only a few.

I'm guessing that "it depends" but if you could point me to something that might help me identify what is causing this it would be much appreciated.  Also if you are interested I could send you the query or any other info you might need.  I'd just rather not post it here.

Comment: Post the query + stats here and we will tell you exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just concerned about the high number of scans of do you really face some performance issue that you attribute to these scans?

How many rows do the tables have where you see these high scan counts? If there are only a handful of rows in a few pages, I wouldn't really bother.

For a start you might find this whitepaper worth reading: 
[Troubleshooting Performance Problems in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966540.aspx)

Comment: I suspect that the high number of scans is the cause of a performance issue i am having.  In the two tables with high scans there are around 8 million records.  I'll check out the article, thanks.

Comment: Next step would be to check the efficiency of your queries. Maybe you're returning more data than is asked for, so that an existing index can't be used optimally and if these queries are optimally supported by your indices. Since you have tagged your question with "SQL Server 2005", have a look at the INCLUDE clause for indices. It can help getting covering indices at a relatively cheap price.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the query run and indexes, and whether your statistics are up to date.

Can you post your table's schema, the query being run and the 'actual' execution plane produced?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the scan count is the number of physical pages that needed to be accessed to execute your query. Simplistically, if there are no (or insufficient) indexes to help then SQL needs to read a lot more pages than it would otherwise. Have you looked at the query plan?